# How to pass a class to a method where the methods parameter is a generic

Tags: c#, generics

This method below has been written 12 different times in my project using a different interface

```
ChannelFactory<interface>
```

and a different "User".

```
var user = new SomeWebServiceReference.User();
```

Examples below.

So I'd like to make a single generic like class or a generic method in a class (not sure what I need) that passes in the "WebServiceAWI" interface and any of the other interfaces (ex. WebServiceBW, WebServiceAWA) and a "User" but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
    // file 1
    public void TestSomething(string url)
    { 
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);

        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WebServiceAWI>(binding, endpoint);

        var webservice = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        var user = new User(); // from ServiceReferenceARM 
        user.UserName = webservice.EncryptValue("someone");
        user.Password = webservice.EncryptValue("password");

        WebServiceResult result = webservice.AttorneysGet(user);
    }

    // file 2
    public void TestSomething(string url)
    { 
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);

        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<WebServiceBW>(binding, endpoint);

        var webservice = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        var user = new User(); // from ServiceReferenceBW
        user.UserName = webservice.EncryptValue("someone");
        user.Password = webservice.EncryptValue("password");

        WebServiceResult result = webservice.AttorneysGet(user);
    }
```

I think I'm on the right track with the interface, but I'm not sure how to pass in a class that then acts like a generic.

Here is what I have so far.

Calling it like this

```
TestTOSomething<WebServiceAWI, WebServicesTO.ServiceReferenceARM.User>(new ServiceReferenceARM.User(), url);
```

and then implementing it like this but I know this is wrong.

```
    public void TestTOSomething<T, K>(K newUser, string url)
    {

        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);

        var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding, endpoint);

        var webservice = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

        var user = newUser;
        user.UserName = webservice.EncryptValue("someone");
        user.Password = webservice.EncryptValue("password");

        WebServiceResult result = webservice.AttorneysGet(user);
    }
```

Comment: If your method expects the type `K` to have `UserName` and `Password` properties, then there's little point in making this generic unless you can constrain `K` to an interface that has those properties.

Answer (score 0):

You could make interfaces for these, and then reference them in your method. There is no need to include the generic type for `newUser` if it isn't being used, just directly use that in the parameters.

As for the WebServiceAWI, you would need to define that type using the `where` keyword.

```
public void TestTOSomething<T>(IUser newUser, string url) where T : IWebServiceAWI
```

Comment: This is correct but you should elaborate the interface

Comment: @AluanHaddad - Based on the level of the question, I am assuming this user understands how to implement an interface. It will also vary greatly depending on their implementation environment.

Comment: I'm not convinced of that. The use of generics is pretty weird in the OP

Comment: yes could you please include an example of the interface?

Comment: also IWebServiceAWI is going to be different webservices so how would I make it generic so I don't hard code "IWebServiceAWI"